# Show in Html a JSON file in Angular

Tags: html, arrays, json, angular, typescript

I'm trying to print a JSON ([link to the JSON](https://api.myjson.com/bins/zbfh5)) in an html file.

JSON:

```
{
  "ricette": {
    "FRIGGITRICI": {
      "Alici": [
        [
          {"500": "scongelamento"}
        ],
        [
          {"60": "nada"}
        ]
      ],
      "Baccalà": [
        [
          {"500": "scongelamento"}
        ],
        [
          {"210": "immerso"},
          {"210": "cestello su"},
          {"30": "immerso"}
        ]
      ]
    },
    "GRIGLIA": {
      "Baccalà": [
        [
          {"500": "scongelamento"}
        ],
        [
          {"210": "immerso"},
          {"210": "cestello su"},
          {"30": "immerso"}
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I've fetched it and saved in a variable:

```
export class DatiService {
  fileJson: JSON;

  constructor() { }

  private datiUrl = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/zbfh5';

  async getDati(){
    await fetch(this.datiUrl)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((out) => {
      this.fileJson=out;
    });
    console.log(this.fileJson);
  };
}
```

How can i print it in the html code?
Can i just use de "." to enter in its fields?
Or it's more complicated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [JsonPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/JsonPipe) in your template.

```
{{fileJson | json}}
```

If you want to print a specific part you can navigate via `.` deeper into the object structure.

```
{{fileJson.ricette.FRIGGITRICI | json}}
```

If you want to print a primitiv value interpolation is enough and no json pipe is needed.

```
{{fileJson.version}}
```

**UPDATE**

Did you called your `getDati` function? Add an ngOnInit [Lifecycle Hook](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) and call it there. [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reldcc) is an working stackblitz sample.

I just realized it's a service in your sample code. Take the service and inject it into a component and call it there.

Comment: Nothing happens in my code... fileJson and the fetch aren't in the html file

Comment: And i updated the answer with a full working sample.

Answer (score -2):

We can use pre tag to view JSON data in HTML
Pass your JSON in var data.
And Set pre tag in HTML body.

```
var data = {Your JSON Object}
$("#json").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2);
<pre id="json"></pre>
```